# Missing Google JSON details

Tags: json, vb.net, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Referencing this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceDetails
I was expecting the JSON result to always hold all of the `address_components` details. However, one of my searches ended up missing street_number, postal_code and one of the others. Looking in intellisense revealed one of the `address_components` returned held an administrative_area_level_2.

This has thrown me into a loop because I was always expecting to have those original values returned even if they were maybe empty. I was also hardcoding the expected return like so:

```
array.result.address_components(0).long_name
```

Since I can't expect the components to return all the results, I need a new way to appropriately access them and figure out what to do when I'm missing some.

Comment: What kinda programming language are we talking about?

Comment: VB.net is what I'm using. I'm thinking I might have to use a select case and examine the types of each component.

Comment: I think you should never make any kinda presumption when it comes to the data you aint generating yourself. Before using a variable make sure the variable exist.

Comment: I am not very sure if in VB.net it is possible to access json nodes using "." or not. You sure it is not javascript?

Comment: Using `(0)` and not `[0]` would indicate VB rather than Javascript. @Mitchell please add the relevant language tags. Looks like SO may need a Google Places tag too.

Comment: Changed the tags. I ended up making a case statement which I'll post in a moment.

Comment: Or I'll do it in 5 hours when I can comment. I'll add an edit since I can't answer.

Comment: For reference, supported address component types can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types The number and type of address components returned are dependent on the data available. If its not available it wont be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the case statement I used to handle this problem. It worked, but not sure if it's the most elegant solution.

```
Dim street As String = ""
Dim city As String = ""
Dim state As String = ""
Dim country As String = ""
Dim zip As String = ""
Dim phone As String = ""
Dim website As String = ""

' No guareentee to the order of even if the data will be there so we check each type. '
For j = 0 To array.result.address_components.Length - 1
    Select Case array.result.address_components(j).types(0)
        Case "street_number"
            street += array.result.address_components(j).long_name()
        Case "route"
            street += " " & array.result.address_components(j).long_name()
        Case "locality"
            city = array.result.address_components(j).long_name()
        Case "administrative_area_level_1"
            state = array.result.address_components(j).long_name()
        Case "country"
            country = array.result.address_components(j).long_name()
        Case "postal_code"
            zip = array.result.address_components(j).long_name()
    End Select
Next
```

I basically cycle through the address_components and check their types value. If the value is one I'm looking for I assign it. I later call Trim() on street to remove that white space I add if there's no street number.